# Does the NuGet feed on GitHub Packages support anonymous access?

Tags: nuget, github-packages

The [GutHub packages page](https://github.com/features/packages) mentions the possibility to "share with the world", and I thought this means anonymous access. But the NuGet feed keep on asking for credentials.

I have created a public [repo](https://github.com/arvesv/PublicPackageTest) with a package, MyPackage. Thus the NuGet feed URL should be https://nuget.pkg.github.com/arvesv/index.json, but any access to the NuGet feed asks for credentials.  Is there a way to allow anonymous access?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a personal access token (PAT) with the `read:packages` scope in order to read public packages. See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries) for details.